# How to Make Samsung Galaxy S10e perform IR?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-10

Now, I know the Samsung Galaxy S10e does *not* have a built-in IR blaster.

However, the [comment at the end of this post](https://www.androidbeat.com/2019/02/samsung-galaxy-s10-ir-blaster/) says the built-in iris scanner has some sort of IR capability?

Is that true, and do you think it's possible to utilize that?

Otherwise, I would use one of those IR remote control apps on Google Play and I'd need an [IR blaster attachment like this.](https://smile.amazon.com/Smart-Remote-Control-iPhone-Conditioner/dp/B07DT9JCLM/ref=pd_sbs_60_8?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07DT9JCLM&pd_rd_r=8f4a78b8-a70d-4dac-98fa-ad5d83ac53fe&pd_rd_w=gd1Lr&pd_rd_wg=KXwQC&pf_rd_p=5873ae95-9063-4a23-9b7e-eafa738c2269&pf_rd_r=VQKHH4ESBE9MWJZEEBVD&psc=1&refRID=VQKHH4ESBE9MWJZEEBVD)  But is this the best way to go?

I'm thinking to control random TVs in hotel and airport lobbies... (just for fun) or the AC at a friend's house or our Stereo receiver we have.